# Unable to start/stop service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service

I have an activity which starts a service. Now, i want to start/stop the service in a BroadcastReceiver which listens to screen off/on. I used:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Log.d("Screen:", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
        context.stopService(new Intent(context, ScreenReceiver.class));
    } 
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
        Log.d("Screen:", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ScreenReceiver.class));
    }
}
}
```

I have added the required permissions and have registered/unregistered the BroadcastReceiver in the service. I am able to see the Log messages in Logcat when i run the code, but the service doesn't seem to stop. How should i fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for starting service pass Service name instead of `ScreenReceiver` (BroadcastReceiver name) to `startService` as second parameter and make sure you have added service in AndroidManifest file

Comment: how is your service defined? context.stopService(new Intent(context, ScreenReceiver.class)); the second arg should be YOURSERVICE.class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to restart your BroadcastReceiver.
 Use you service class instead.

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, ScreenReceiver.class));
```

should be

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
```

and in your manifest file:

```
<service android:name=".YourService"></service>
```

Comment: he just has problem in stopping

Comment: @kevinhoo, either way this code wont start his service. Probably he got the service started from somewhere else.

Comment: I changed it to the service class. But the problem persists. The onDestroy() method in the service gets executed when i call stopService() right?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be called! Is your service bound?

Comment: No. I am not using a bounded service. I want the service to be stopped when the phone is locked and i want to start it up once it is unlocked. But am guessing its not possible as i came across many articles which say onDestroy() is not called immediately. Rather it is called only when the OS wants to free up the memory space.